# How would I make a value in a mysql table echo as something else?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, echo

I'd like the easiest way to echo a value in a mysql table as something else. Example:

```
 <option value="1">Member</option>
 <option value="2">Admin</option>
```

It gets entered into mysql as value 1 or value 2.

When I call it from mysql table like this:

```
    echo '<td>'. $row['rank'] . '</td>';
```

It shows up as either value 1 or value 2. I want it to show up as Member or Admin. I would I go about doing this in the easiest way possible?

Comment: @juhana No but I'm pulling it from the database as the value of 1 or 2. Therefor that wouldn't work as in the row it would show up as 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo '<td>'. member_rank($row['rank']) . '</td>';

    function member_rank($id) {
    if($id == 1):
    $rank = "Member";
    elseif($id == 2):
    $rank = "Admin";
    endif;
    return $rank;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your rank names in an associative array, where the key is the rank ID of your DB:

```
$rank=array(1=>'member', 2=>'admin');  
echo $rank[$row['rank']];
```

Comment: Or in db, add a table `ranks` with cols `id` and `rank`, then in your select request, you add a joint with this table: `joint on yourrank=ranks.id` so you can add `ranks.rank` to selected fields. Less simple but maybe better to have all data in database.